# Rebuild PHP/MySQL site as a Windows based program

Tags: windows, microsoft-word

I have a CRUD web app built in PHP/MySQL. The app basically takes in user data, adds word document templates, and creates finished Word documents. I have determined it would be better for my audience which is concerned about data privacy over the internet to rebuild this app as a program that can be run on Windows with all data saved locally. In the short run I am thinking of just setting up the site code to run on Server2Go for Windows, but in the long run I really want to recreate the app as a Windows installable program.

Can somebody point me to a good relatively recent tutorial on doing this? I have a lot of things bouncing around my head about this and not sure which direction to go in, and I have the requirement of being able to create word documents from templete forms. Maybe if somebody points me in the right direction I can eventually get this started. Thanks for any answers you may have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you are thinking about using Word automation on the client machine? If you are going to have this functionality included in your Windows based program that is distributed to your customers you are going to have make sure that they have Microsoft Word installed or it won't work.

You should be looking for a stand-alone thirty party that doesn't require Microsoft Word to be installed to work. Check out Aspose.Words for .NET for instance which has a great reputation for this exact task.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Since you were the only one to answer, I will go ahead and accept your answer. Looks like I am going to be learning a lot about .NET soon.